# A question regarding matrix rings and semiprime matrix ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I am fascinated by matrix rings and their ideals. I am trying to solve a specific problem. First, we recall that any two-sided ideal of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$ where I is an ideal of the ring $R$, which is commutative and has $1$. Sands in his paper [1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/AC3C7D5619CE19CCA26A09AD3ABF8922/S2040618500033335a.pdf/prime-ideals-in-matrix-rings.pdf) proved that semiprime ideals of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$, where $I$ is also a semiprime ideal of $R$. My claim is

> If every element $x$ of a semiprime ideal $I$ of $R$ is of the form $x=yz$ for some $y,z\in I$, then any element $A\in M_n(I)$ is of the form $A=BC$ for some elements $B,C\in M_n(I)$.

The converse is easy. I need to prove this direction. Can anyone please help?